# R : wrong format when i construct a matrix from vector with Date

Tags: r

I'm new with R language, and currently trying to build a matrix from 4 vector. Seems ok, but not for one column, which is a Date type, I convert it before, I print it, it's ok, but when I build my matrix, it's completely wrong.

Here is my code:

```
species<-c('a','a','a','b','b','c')
species
date_vec<-c(as.Date("2012/04/20",format='%Y/%m/%d'),
    as.Date('1999-10-07',format='%Y-%m-%d'),
    as.Date('2000-01-01',format='%Y-%m-%d'),
    as.Date('1995-01-15',format='%Y-%m-%d'),
    as.Date('1996-08-12',format='%Y-%m-%d'),
    as.Date('2005-04-09',format='%Y-%m-%d'))
date_vec
x<-c(3.456788,3.455314,3.452113,4.51779,5.681133,5.650492)
x
y<-c(51.15573,51.15889,51.15722,51.12166,50.22464,50.21053)
y
vec_resu<-c(species,date_vec,x,y)
vec_resu
mat_recap<-matrix(vec_resu ,nrow=6,ncol=4, byrow=FALSE)
mat_recap`
```

Here is my date_vec:

```
date_vec
[1] "2012-04-20" "1999-10-07" "2000-01-01" "1995-01-15" "1996-08-12" "2005-04-09"
```

And here is my matrix:

```
mat_recap
     [,1] [,2]    [,3]       [,4]      
[1,] "a"  "15450" "3.456788" "51.15573"
[2,] "a"  "10871" "3.455314" "51.15889"
[3,] "a"  "10957" "3.452113" "51.15722"
[4,] "b"  "9145"  "4.51779"  "51.12166"
[5,] "b"  "9720"  "5.681133" "50.22464"
[6,] "c"  "12882" "5.650492" "50.21053"
```

I don't understand why I have so much difference, and why it's completely wrong in the matrix!

If you have any hint, that would be nice!

Comment: The problem is that matrices can hold only one type of data, you are mixing characters, dates and numbers, therefore, everything is coreced to a common denominator, class `character`. Use `data.frame(species, date_vec, x, y)` instead.

Comment: Yes of course, i completely forgot --' Thanks a lot !